# How can I show that a continuous homegenous operator maps a maximal connected element to itself?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

this is not a homework problem but its part of a proof that I am reading but I have no clue why it is true

Given that $T$(a map from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$) is a continuous and homegenous operator ($T(cx)=cT(x),\forall c>0,x \in \mathbb{R}^m$)
Let $V$(a map from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}$, we also know that it's a continuous lyapunov function and is defined on a neighborhood of the origin ) be defined over the closure of the unit ball and let $m_0=\inf_{\|x\|=1} V(x)$ and $G$ be the maximal connected component of $\{x:V(x)<\frac{1}{2}m_0\}$  which contains the origin. Then how can I show that $$T(\bar{G}) \subset G$$

Comment: You do not list any relation between $T$ and $V$. Say $V$ is the norm and $T(x)=3x$, then it doesn't look like $T(\bar{G}) \subset G$. You might need to provide more details.

Comment: @Mirko I apologize , in a hurry I forgot to mention that V is a continuous lyapunov function in the neighborhood of the origin . There is no connection mentioned in the paper between V and T . :(